# Is this "Collections and Sequences" Documentation topic too broad?

Tags: discussion, documentation

Earlier today, a [request](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/clojure/topic-requests/1036) was made for a "Collections and Sequences" topic in the [Clojure Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/clojure):

> Built in Clojure collection data structures and an explanation of the Sequence abstractions.

So I [wrote one](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/clojure/1389/collections-and-sequences). I organized it like this:

- [stuff relevant to all collections](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/clojure/1389/collections-and-sequences/4526/collections)
- specific collections

  - [lists](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/clojure/1389/collections-and-sequences/4527/lists)
  - [vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/clojure/1389/collections-and-sequences/4529/vectors)
  - [maps](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/clojure/1389/collections-and-sequences/4531/maps)
  - [sets](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/clojure/1389/collections-and-sequences/4530/sets)
- [sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/clojure/1389/collections-and-sequences/4528/sequences)

I wanted to separate it by collection type, and overall, I think that it turned out pretty well. I'm concerned that this isn't how Documentation is supposed to be used, though. For one thing, it looks like there's no way to control the ordering of examples. I would have liked for the examples to be ordered like this:

- [Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/clojure/1389/collections-and-sequences/4526/collections)
- [Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/clojure/1389/collections-and-sequences/4527/lists)
- [Vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/clojure/1389/collections-and-sequences/4529/vectors)
- [Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/clojure/1389/collections-and-sequences/4531/maps)
- [Sets](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/clojure/1389/collections-and-sequences/4530/sets)
- [Sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/clojure/1389/collections-and-sequences/4528/sequences)

However, after shifting around several times while I was writing, the ordering seems to have settled as this:

- [Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/clojure/1389/collections-and-sequences/4526/collections)
- [Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/clojure/1389/collections-and-sequences/4527/lists)
- [Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/clojure/1389/collections-and-sequences/4531/maps)
- [Sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/clojure/1389/collections-and-sequences/4528/sequences)
- [Sets](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/clojure/1389/collections-and-sequences/4530/sets)
- [Vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/clojure/1389/collections-and-sequences/4529/vectors)

This isn't terrible, but it could have been worse, and it voids some of the implicit assumption that I had while writing it.

In addition, each of the "examples" are fairly long, covering all the basic operations on each standard collection type.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Should there perhaps be six topics (one for each of the existing examples), with smaller examples? Or is the current organization OK?

Comment: "Should there perhaps be six topics (one for each of the existing examples), with smaller examples?" That's the question. I guess the optimal size of a topic and guidelines on when and how to split are currently still be discussed. For this example: In a traditional Java book Collections are a whole chapter and each type is a section in the chapter. If we equate topics with sections it would probably mean we should split the collections topic. No intentional order of examples is another subject though.